# Ag-grid update custom-element cell-renderer value

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I have a column with custom-cell-renderer and custom-cell-editor.

However when changing the value in the editor the renderer does not get the new value from the editor.

I tried to update the value inside

```
MyCellRenderer.prototype.refresh(params){this.rendererElement.value = params.newValue};
```

But the params Object there does not contain the new Value.

Also tried the `newValueHandler` callback. There the new value is present but I have no reference to the current cell-renderer-component.

Comment: can you explain the flow of your actions? are you trying to apply the cell renderer on the updated value from cell editor? and why would you need new Value on cell renderer because cell renderer should not ideally care if it is a new value or old value

Comment: yes I want that the renderer gets the updated value from the cell editor.
I dont care about the naming new Value or value. You can just call it "updated value from the editor" 

Flow: click onto a cell -> editor is shown -> edit the value -> leave editor(enter, outside-click...) -> renderer should show the "new" value from the editor

Edit: The cell renderer/editor are custom "polymer" components. If that matters.

Comment: in your cell editor are you implementing the getValue()? This should return 'value' to cellRenderer in params.value